# Cannot find module ".package.json" when requiring a module in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, webpack, node-modules

I am trying to import a node module into my Angular 2 application :

```
const node-module = require('some-module');
```

In the console I always get the error

```
ERROR in ./~/some-module/package.json
Module parse failed: /home/tom/Projects/project/node_modules/some-module     /package.json Unexpected token (2:9)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (2:9)
```

I am using Webpack for bundling modules and I don't really get why this is failing. 
Is there some other way of importing node modules in Angular 2 applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's trying to load even package.json witch it should not. you can try json-loader if that work, however it should not compile package.json, package.json should be excluded from bundling.

Comment: No, the package.json file in the module is valid, I have checked it with various tools on the web like you said. Something else must be the problem.

Comment: when you do this const node-module = require('some-module'); it take everything. you are using webpack you can simply use import like import {yourModule} from "some-module"

Comment: [Please take a look](https://github.com/blinfo/angular2-webpack-seed)

and also try this
{test: /\.json$/, loader: "json-loader"}

Comment: Thank you for your answers  MrJSingh, after I added {test: /\.json$/, loader: "json-loader"} there were no errors, but I will also take a look at the angular2-webpack-seed. Thanks again! I will make your answer the correct one as soon as I can.